# vhdl ram module and use of registers

Tags: vhdl

Ok another question in VHDL. Below is my code. Suppose that I want my input stored in ram. And lets say I want to add two of them. (do not give emphasis on it, later on it will be replaced). This is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

use work.my_package.all;

entity landmark_1 is
  generic
        (data_length :integer := 8;
        address_length:integer:=3 );
        port ( clk:in std_logic;
        vin:in std_logic;
        rst:in std_logic;
        flag: in std_logic;
        din: in signed(data_length -1 downto 0);
        done: out std_logic
        );
end landmark_1;

architecture TB_ARCHITECTURE of landmark_1 is


component ram IS
    generic
    (
        ADDRESS_WIDTH   : integer := 4;
        DATA_WIDTH  : integer := 8
    );
    port
    (
        clock           : IN  std_logic;
        data            : IN  signed(DATA_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
        write_address           : IN  unsigned(ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
        read_address            : IN  unsigned(ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
        we          : IN  std_logic;
        q           : OUT signed(DATA_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end component;

signal inp1,inp2: matrix1_t(0 to address_length);
signal out_temp: signed(data_length-1 downto 0);
signal k:unsigned(address_length-1 downto 0);

signal i: integer range 0 to 100:=0;
begin

read1:ram generic map( ADDRESS_WIDTH=>address_length, DATA_WIDTH=>data_length) port map (clk,din,k,k,vin,out_temp);
inp1(i)<=out_temp;

process (clk)
  begin
  if (clk'event and clk='1') then 
    if (flag='1') then out_temp<=inp1(0)+inp1(1);
    end if;
  end if; 
end process ;   

end TB_ARCHITECTURE;
```

Below are my questions:

1. Why to use that ram and not just do `inp(i)<=din;` . I think that it will help synthesizer understand that this is a ram, but what else? Moreover, do I need `inp1` registers. And if I a going to use them, again why use ram as an intermediate?
2. If inp1 is unnecessary, how I am going to fetch these two elements in my process? I mean I need something like `ram(address1)+ram(address2)`, right?

Below is my ram_code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY ram IS
    GENERIC
    (
        ADDRESS_WIDTH   : integer := 4;
        DATA_WIDTH  : integer := 8
    );
    PORT
    (
        clock           : IN  std_logic;
        data            : IN  signed(DATA_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
        write_address           : IN  unsigned(ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
        read_address            : IN  unsigned(ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
        we          : IN  std_logic;
        q           : OUT signed(DATA_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END ram;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF ram IS
    TYPE RAM IS ARRAY(0 TO 2 ** ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1) OF signed(DATA_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);

    SIGNAL ram_block : RAM;
BEGIN
    PROCESS (clock)
    BEGIN
        IF (clock'event AND clock = '1') THEN
            IF (we = '1') THEN
                ram_block(to_integer(unsigned(write_address))) <= data;
            END IF;

            q <= ram_block(to_integer(unsigned(read_address)));
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END rtl;
```

3.can anyone tell me why the q (output) is estimated one clock later?

EDIT: To sum up,I was told that I should use a ram and this is my implementation. The question is what I have gained by changing my `inp1(i)<=din;` when I inserted the ram model. And there fore how can I use it? (before using the ram I waws just wrote i`np1(i)+inp2(i+1)` for example).

EDIT2: PACKAGE FOR TYPES.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package my_package is
    type matrix1_t is array(integer range<>) of signed(7 downto 0);
    type big_matrix is array(integer range<>) of signed(23 downto 0);
    type matrix2d is array (integer range<>) of big_matrix(0 to 3);

end my_package;
```

Comment: Please can you edit your code to remove bits that are commented out, and indent it properly.  If you want us to help you, you'll get better responses if you make it as easy as possible for us to read about your problem.

Comment: ok, I have edited my answer and removed comments

Comment: I didn't mean remove comments - just the bits of *code* that are commented out!

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you have some dead code: `inp2` is never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why to use that ram and not just do inp(i)<=din;

In real world designs you use RAMs to store large amounts of data because they are smaller (physically, on the chip) that arrays of flip flops. During the synthesis process the RAM is replaced by one from your vendor's library. This RAM looks rather small, but I'm guessing you've been told to use one as an exercise.

> Moreover, do I need inp1 registers. And if I a going to use them, again why use ram as an intermediate?

I'm not quite sure what imp1 is, as I don't know what a `matrix_t` is, but I'm guessing it's a register version of the RAM. In which case it's redundant.

> If inp1 is unnecessary, how I am going to fetch these two elements in my process? I mean I need something like ram(address1)+ram(address2), right?

...and there's the real issue. You need to ask yourself 'If you can't read more that one thing in a cycle, how do you add two numbers?'

> can anyone tell me why the q (output) is estimated one clock later?

Because that's how RAMs work. You apply an address in one cycle, and the data appears some cycles later (normally one, but not always)

These are real issues that you'll face in real designs. RAMs are necessary because of their smaller size. You need to know the issues that surround using them and how to work with them.

Comment: Great post to help me understand. So a final question and I will check your answer. Lets say that I want to fetch elements from ram not in the same cycle, but some time later. Will I have to port map again and take from my output the element I want (with we='0' for example)? What I do mean is that there is not an easy way-just write  ram_block(address) and fetch that element, as I would normally do in a register,right? Inp1 is just an array that copies the ram elements, therefore is redundant.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I think you're asking if you could read and write in the same cycle, and the answer would be dependent on the design of the RAM. Some RAMs have separate read and write ports to allow this. Others have a combined ports. Yours has a separate read address and write address, so you can do both independently, but be careful when they're both the same address.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting `i` to anything other than `0` so you will only ever assign to `inp1(0)`.

Assuming the RAM is there to store many values, and you need to read two of them every clock cycle in order to do your adding, you need 2 RAM blocks (or a single dual-ported one) and then put the two addresses into those RAM blocks.  The next cycle the two values you want will appear on the data outputs and you can sum them.

The clock-cycle delay you observe is in the nature of synchronous RAMs (which is what most FPGAs have for their "large storage") - some can create smaller asynchronous RAMs where the data appears a short delay after the read address changes, completely asynchronously to the clock.

Comment: The actual computation is different than this difference. And the index i change its value from a testbench. just to understand how to make writing procedure to ram independent from reading from the ram (My computation required that all the data have been read first).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to represent a RAM with the signal `inp1`. However, the signal that represents the RAM is `ram_block` in your `ram` entity.

You are using the entity in a strange way because you connect the signal `k` as read and write address. There are two problems with that. Firstly, `k` doesn't seem to be driven anywhere in your design. Secondly, you probably don't want the two addresses to be the same.

I assume you want to write some values to the RAM and at the same time read two values and add them up. I suggest you use a process that sets a write address and a process that sets a read address. You also need at least one register with the width of the RAM output. The first value you read from the RAM is stored in that register. Then you add the value in that register and the second value read from the RAM and store the result in a different register.

Comment: well yes. I was told that I should use a ram and this is my implementation. The question is what I have gained by changing my inp1(i)<=din; when I inserted the ram model. And there fore how can I use it?

Comment: But to implement what? Can you show the definition of the `matrix_1t` type?

Comment: edited. Well imagine my previous code was something like this.
process(clk)
inp(i)<=din
...change i
end process

and now I replaced that with the ram model because the synthesizer gave me warnings on that that it cannot identify inp1 array as a ram module.

Comment: Can you further explain me this: " You also need at least one register with the width of the RAM output. The first value you read from the RAM is stored in that register. Then you add the value in that register and the second value read from the RAM and store the result in a different register." What If I want to be read on later times? How can I fetch this ram_block array, as it is defined in another module?

Comment: Assume your ram_block array has depth 2. Initially the content of the array is undefined. If you want to write values to the RAM, you set `din` to the value you want to store, the write address to 0 or 1 (depending on where you want to store your value) and `vin` to 1 for one cycle. The value will remain in the ram internal `ram_block` array until it is overwritten. You can retrieve it by setting the read address to 0 or 1 (the same address as you wrote the value to). The value will then be at the output in the next cycle.

Comment: Ok but this output (in the next cycle) needs to be stored somewhere if I want to be accessible for later use, right? Otherwise I will have to port map again,right?

Comment: Yes, the output will change in the cycle after you change the read address. Only one value that was stored in the RAM can be present at the output at once.